# Apache redirection issue with https

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I have a site hosted on a server at /start/.

In the Apache conf file, I redirect all requests for "/" to "/start/" using the simple rule below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/?$  /start/  [R]
```

When I access "http://foo.bar/" the browser is redirected to "http://foo.bar/start/" successfully.

But, when I access "https://foo.bar/", the browser is not redirected to /start/ and instead shows the default Apache welcome page.

What do I have to do to handle https request in a special way?

Note: The site can be accessed successfully behind https. Eg: If I directly access "https://foo.bar/start/", I see the expected page.

The full conf file:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/?$  /start/  [R]

ProxyRequests Off
LogLevel warn

Proxy http://127.0.0.1:8083/
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
/Proxy

Location /start/
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8083/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8083/
/Location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is the complete config because I don't see the SSL vhost defintion.

If these statements are in the default server config (i.e., not in an explicit vhost) then you need to put `RewriteOptions inherit` in the SSL vhost definition.

If they are in a specific vhost conifig then you need to (a) move them into the default server config and add `RewriteOptions inherit` in the SSL vhost definition or (b) copy them into the SSL vhost definition.

Comment: The SSL vhost configuration is in the default file installed by the mod_ssl package on Redhat systems.

By adding
<pre>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
</pre> 

To the bottom of the VirtualHost section in ssl.conf, I got the redirect to work as I wanted it to.

Thank you.